# How to get spatial sound in a 2D app in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a checkpoint in my 2D game which in small radius should make a sound. But sound is still playing even if player left a distance. I tried to set settings in audio source:

```
Max distance = 2
```

and

```
Volume Rolloff = Linear Rolloff
```

also

```
Spatial Blend = 1
```

but after this I don't hear sound at all.

Is it not working for 2D?

Comment: Is the `AudioListener` in your scene attached to the player or the camera? By default the distance etc depends on how far your **Camera** is away from the `AudioSource` .. in a 2D game I'ld suspect the camera staying at its position or at least moving always at a fix distance to the action plane where your player and objects are placed ... I think you could change that by removing the `AudioListener` from the camera and rather attach one to your player object.

Comment: It doesn't help. I removed AudioListener from Camera and add it to player but I can still hear music off the distance

Comment: With the Spatial Blend enabled?

Comment: I forgot about it. Now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that matters is how far your [`AudioListener`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/class-AudioListener.html) in the scene is away from the `AudioSource`

By default the `AudioListener` is on your `MainCamera`. In a 2D game I'ld suspect the camera staying at its position or at least moving always at a fix distance to the action plane where your player and objects are placed.

But actually you can move that `AudioListener` component to whatever `GameObject` you want in order to make it responsible for receiving the different `AudioSource`s of your scene.

So you could/should in a 2D app change that by removing the `AudioListener` from the camera and rather attach one to your player object.

And then it is important to enable the `Spatial Blend` but you already did that.

Answer (score 0):

Audiosource settings:

```
Spatial Blend: 1
Volume Rolloff: = Linear Rolloff
Min distance = 1
Max distance = 30
```

Place the audio listener on your player object or whatever you want